# Returned DataTable from SQL command "SHOW TABLE STATUS"

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, sql

When running the command in mySQL workbench, the command "SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'tableName'" returns a single row with 23 columns. I want the "Auto_increment" column, which for reasoning, we shall say i already know i could find like so, assuming i've already connected, sent the query, and populated a DataTable;

```
dataTable = mDBConnector.Select("SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'x'");
MessageBox.Show(dataTable.Rows[0][15].ToString());
//alternatively
//MessageBox.Show(dataTable.Rows[0]["Auto_increment"].ToString());
```

However, when running the query from within my application, it returns basically nothing...the same query that returns the expected results when run from within the MySQL workbench.

I'm sure it's not to do with permissions, as i'm testing with even root access for the sake of testing, and i know it's not how i'm retrieving data from within my application or the connection, as i use this throughout and have never had problems with it.

Has anyone ran into this before and knows an answer?

edit: The query i'm using is as follows (i'm using real table / column details now so i'll remove these after. Tearing my hair out here!)

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'bf-2300' AND table_name = 'devices';
```

In MySQL workbench, i get the following:

[image: test]

As you can see, it returns values correctly.
However, when i run the query in my program and return the datatable, it does NOT contain this information and i don't know why. It's almost as if it isn't acting as a normal DataTable.

I'm trying to get the column "auto increment" as explained above. Normally i could just pick dataTable.Rows[0]["colname"] but these contain no values - on a query which works in workbench and it's definitely not my methods for filling the DataTable as this stuff works flawlessly throughout my program. What's strange is that it's returning the query result column names, just not the information for that row.

Comment: can you execute any other query using mDBConnector.select and see the result if its fetching ?

Comment: Check current database. Is it correct? Try to use 'SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM db_name...' statement.

Comment: @Devart I tried SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'database.table', which doesn't error in workbench but shows nothing for all columns. I can't seem to get "SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM db_name LIKE 'x'; to work.

Comment: What is the MySQL version? What is the error?

Comment: 0 11:35:40 SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM d-b LIKE 'x' Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-b LIKE 'x'' at line 1. I put the hyphon in the database name, as there's one in the real one and i wasn't sure if that might be causing a problem.

Comment: The name d-b must be quoted - SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM \`d-b\` LIKE 'devices'.

Comment: Theres a chance i was trying to use the schema instead of the db, lemme just check that.

Comment: Getting denied user now. Although i'm not sure this is the right thing i'm doing. Quoting the db name also gave another error similar to the one before.

Comment: It should work. What is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another, and maybe better way, is to use [information_schema.table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/tables-table.html) to get information about tables.

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.table
WHERE table_schema = 'db_name' AND table_name = 'table_name';
```

Comment: changing table to tables seems to work, at least in the workbench, ill try it in my app now. edit: still returned nothing.

Comment: I may have figured it out. When running it from my program it seems to add 2 rows, instead of the expected 1. The first row contains just the column names from the table itself that i'm getting information about, which is weird because it doesn't show this in the workbench query browser..

Comment: Maybe DataTable is not filled. Try to use IDataReader instead of filling table - create a command with SELECT query, and run command.ExecuteReader method, then read records - one by one.

Comment: This worked, i think it fills the DataTable with an extra row though, i just had to point it at the correct one.